# How to import an image in React if the path of your image is not working

Tags: reactjs

My image path is not working, I did a better solution for my case I hope this works for you too.

The problem for my case is:

I did use

```
import logo from './components/image/Serenity.png';
```

but the problem with this is when I put it on

```
<img={logo} alt=''/>
```

it doesn't work.

So the solution for my problem is:

Instead of `import logo from './components/image/Serenity.png';`

I did one of these

- `import logo from '../images/Serenity.png';`
- `const logo = require("../images/Serenity.png")`

then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

In react-app put all images in `public folder` and access them like this:

```
<img src = {'/Serenity.png'}/>
```

**!NOTE:** you no need to add the path to the public folder

Comment: `/your path in public folder`